# Celery Function not called

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, celery

I try to create a progress bar with celery. 
Unfortunately my worker function get not called.

```
def checkconfig_post_new (request):
    job = do_work.delay()
    print ("Work started")
    return HttpResponseRedirect ( reverse ( 'poll_state' ) + '?job=' + job.id )


# this decorator is all that's needed to tell celery this is a worker task
@task()
def do_work():
    for i in range(10):
        sleep(0.1)
        print (i)
        current_task.update_state(state='PROGRESS',
            meta={'current': i, 'total': 10})
```

The print statement "Work started" will never be printed out. Also the "i" will never be printed.

It seems, that the program will stop working.

Here is the full code:

**celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'devadmin.settings')

app = Celery('devadmin')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**__init__.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

**views.py**

```
from celery import task, current_task
from celery.result import AsyncResult
from time import sleep

def checkconfig_post_new (request):
    job = do_work.delay()
    print ("Work started")
    return HttpResponseRedirect ( reverse ( 'poll_state' ) + '?job=' + job.id )
```

**tasks.py**

```
@task()
    def do_work():
        for i in range(10):
            sleep(0.1)
            print (i)
            current_task.update_state(state='PROGRESS',
                meta={'current': i, 'total': 10})
```

Comment: Have you started the celery workers?

Comment: More information would help here. How do you call the task, is celery logging anything interesting. Your example is not complete (i.e. imports are missing) so if I wanted to run it here I am not able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Your task has to be registered with celery in *tasks.py* - if celery was loaded without being aware of this task and did not register it, it will never know about it.

Comment: I created a file called task.py and moved the task do_work() in this file. Unfortunately it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

1st, check the registered tasks of your's worker (launch it 2x, sometimes its empty the 1st print).

```
from celery.task.control import  inspect
i = inspect()
i.registered_tasks()
```

2nd you need to put your task in a `tasks.py`, because `autodiscover_tasks` search this pattern.